# EditText with number keyboard(inputType) doesn't write numbers

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText with `android:inputType="number"` and **doesn't write anything(numbers)** when I press the numbers. The EditText is inside a **dialog**.

If I change number to `numberSigned`, the negative character it's OK, is possible to write, but not numbers.

When I change to `android:inputType="phone"`, it doesn't work. But I change to "text" I can write numbers and text....
Same problem writting programatically `setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);`
and siscarded problem with mobile.

I don't know what is happening...

XML code:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edTxtGenerarMicroPersonalizado"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:hint="Personalizado"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Edit Text declaration:

```
final EditText edTxtPersonalizado;
edTxtPersonalizado = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edTxtGenerarMicroPersonalizado);
edTxtPersonalizado.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(4)});
edTxtPersonalizado.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
edTxtPersonalizado.requestFocus();
imm.showSoftInput(edTxtPersonalizado, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT); //Same problem without this
```

Comment: What will happen if you remove the android:digits="0123456789"

Comment: @F.sh the same... The digits it's to filter only number with text keyboard. Thanks

Comment: I know, but did you try to remove the filters?

Comment: @F.sh yes and hasn't resolved the problem. I put the digits after the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

also, you have `android:visibility="gone"`, so your EditText is not being shown

Comment: The same with numberDecimal.
There is a setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); to show the EditText when I want..
Thanks